# Having some trouble with my equals button

Tags: c#

this is the first real program I'm making for school, and I'm having some trouble with it. I believe my case structure and everything else is right, but when I attempt to add two numbers in my calculator, the text property for label 7 does not update.

This is my sample of how I have my case structure set up:

```
    private void radioButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
            rb = 5;
    }
```

and then the actual case structure itself, as well as the rest of the code:

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        double result = 0;
        string resultInLabel;

        switch (rb)
        {
            case 1:
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case 2:
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case 3:
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case 4:
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
        }
        resultInLabel = Convert.ToString(result);
        resultInLabel = label7.Text;
    }
```

button1 is my equals button, forgot to rename it. If more code is needed please let me know, first time posting and unsure how much more context is needed. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You are not updating the text of label7 in this code.

Comment: I know, trying to ask why it's not updating. I set resultInLabel to be label7.Text, and it's not working, so what did I do wrong? I've also moved num1, num2, result, and resultInLabel, to be global, so they are no longer in the button1 code.

Comment: Why would changing a random variable named `resultInLabel` also change the text of label7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the text of the label you have to assign a value to it, not read its current value. Make your last line the following:

```
label7.Text = resultInLabel;
```